# How to acquire a lock in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, locks

Can any one helps me to understand how to lock variables in c++ in the most simple example, pretending I need to lock 2 variables in a function or a thread

Comment: You mean like this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard?

Comment: You mean a mutually exclusive lock like `std::mutex`?

Comment: example in cppreference is more than enough, it's quite simple.

Comment: Can I lock a variable of type int ?

Comment: @Arwa196 _"Can I lock a variable of type int ?"_ Did you actually read the sample there?

Comment: No, you don't lock just any variable, the lock itself is a variable you use in order to ensure you have ownership of some critical section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
int a;
int b;
std::mutex mutex;
```

Just do:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
    ++a; // or whatever you wanna do to a
    b += a; // or whatever you wanna do to b
}
```

This will release the lock at the `}` automatically.

If you want to make sure that a lock is acquired before accessing the variables in question, you'll have to write a wrapper.

Comment: this will lock a and b for the {  } scope,Right ?  what if I don't need to lock all the variables in that scope ?

Comment: No, it locks `mutex`. If you want to be sure the mutex is locked when accessing `a` and `b`, you'll have to write a wrapper as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You cannot lock arbitrary variables. You can only lock objects that have a `lock` method (see [`BasicLockable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable)).